# How to launch a Google Deep learning VM from google python client?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client, google-dl-platform

`GCP` has a deep learning VM available to run on their cloud compute platform. The details about the image is [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning)

So, I am using the google python client to launch my instances and the documentation for this is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert). Now, the way one specifies the disk and the boot image is through this JSON blob:

```
'disks': [
            {
                'boot': True,
                'autoDelete': True,
                'initializeParams': {
                    'sourceImage': source_disk_image,
                }
            }
        ]
```

Now the `source_disk_image` is specified by the path to some public image like:

`projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9` or some variant of this type. Now, my question is how can I specify some marketplace image to be used for my instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not attached to using the marketplace to create the VM, there's a lot of documentation about all the available [Google Deep Learning images](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/images).

They live in the `deeplearning-platform-release` project, so, for example, I think (but am not sure) the default image you are referring to from the Marketplace you linked is `projects/deeplearning-platform-release/global/images/tf-1-14-cu100-20191004` but you can also pull them by family and just get the latest versions, for example, `projects/deeplearning-platform-release/global/images/family/tf-latest-gpu`.

The `gcloud images` command is also pretty illuminating to see the description of a given family choice or image, e.g.:

```
$ gcloud compute images describe-from-family tf-latest-gpu --project deeplearning-platform-release
archiveSizeBytes: '322993843200'
creationTimestamp: '2019-10-06T13:57:56.932-07:00'
description: "Google, Deep Learning Image: TensorFlow 1.14.0, m36, TensorFlow 1.14.0\
  \ with CUDA 10.0 and Intel\xAE MKL-DNN, Intel\xAE MKL."
diskSizeGb: '30'
...
```

Which looks a lot like the Marketplace description.

That said, it looks like the Marketplace might be doing other things though (e.g. there are checkboxes about installing particular drivers separate from choosing the image).

I think that @Ernesto's tip about creating an instance off the marketplace, and then viewing that instance via the REST link at the bottom of the instance page to find exactly how it was created is also good advice.  However, in this case you probably want to view the *disk* that was created (not the instance, since once it is created it only references the disk resource), click on the rest link, and look for the "sourceImage" portion of the REST response.

e.g. from a regular old debian-9 disk (I don't have GPU quota so I can't actually create the marketplace deployment):

[image: Bottom of Disk instance page]

---

[image: relevant json]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the SourceImage of a Deep Learning found in the marketplace, for this example I'm using 
**NVIDIA GPU Cloud Image for Deep Learning, Data Science, and HPC**

```
"name": "nvidia-gpu-cloud-image-20190809",
  "selfLink": "projects/nvidia-ngc-public/global/images/nvidia-gpu-cloud-image-20190809",
  "sourceDisk": "projects/nvidia-ngc-dev/zones/us-central1-a/disks/chetan-official-base-image"
```

1. Deploy an instance from the MarketPlace
2. Go to the instance and inspect the details from the UI
3. In the Boot disk section click on the image name
   nvidia-gpu-cloud-image-20190809 it will take you to the image
   details page
4. Click on REST at the bottom of the description
5. Find SelfLink or SourceDisk entry

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see any 'image details' at least in the GCP UI I have. I clicked on 'Deploy' on the page I linked above and the same with the nvidia image.